# Plot including one categorical variable and two numeric variables

Tags: r, algorithm

How can I show the values of AverageTime and AverageCost for their corresponding type on a graph. The scale of the variables is different since one of them is the average of time and another one is the average of cost. I  want to define type as x and y refers to the value of AverageTime and AverageCost. (In this case, I will have two line plots just in one graph)

```
Type<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k")
AverageTime<-c(12,14,66,123,14,33,44,55,55,6,66)
AverageCost<-c(100,10000,400,20000,500000,5000,700,800,400000,500,120000)
df<-data.frame(Type,AverageTime,AverageCost)
```

Comment: @MLavoie, thanks so much for your reply. I want to have two Line plots in just one graph, The x refers to the levels of type and line plot1 shows the value of AverageTime and bar plot2 shows the value of Averagecost.

Comment: do you want to show the average for each x or do you want to show both values for each letter

Comment: @MLavoie: I want to Show both values for each type.

Comment: You are right, I modified the question.

Comment: you can still use my answer, but just replace the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done using `facet_wrap` and `scales="free_y"` like so:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  mutate(AverageCost=as.numeric(AverageCost), AverageTime=as.numeric(AverageTime)) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Type) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Type, y=value, colour=variable, group=variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales="free_y")
```

[image]

There you can compare the two lines even though they are different scales.

HTH

Comment: thanks for your reply, But I prefer to have type as a "x" to see the trend of Averagecost and AverageTime better. I mean I want to have two bar lines in just one plot.

Comment: Thanks for your great solution, I was wondering why you used summarise(value.mean=mean(value)) in your solution since we donot have duplicated type.

Comment: A vestige of your previous dataset. Edited now.

Comment: @shoorideh Can you show where and how you are using `is.na()`?

Comment: @ boshek, I fixed the issue. Again, thanks so much for your great solution.

Comment: Hi boshek, I would be grateful if you could please let me ask you another question. How can I adjust the scale of some variables in your solution. For example, one of the plots(0<y<6000) although all values are less than 100.

Comment: I think that you want the scales argument from facet_wrap. You can choose from a few options. See `?facet_wrap` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(AverageTime, AverageCost, colour=Type)) + geom_point()
p + geom_abline()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, but I want to define type as x and y refers to AverageCost and AverageTime. Then I can see , the values of AverageTime and AverageCost for each level of type.

Comment: Could you rephrase what you are looking for or maybe illustrate it in some way?

Answer (score 0):

To show both lines in the same plot it will be hard since there are on different scales. You also need to convert AverageTime and AverageCost into a numeric variable.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
```

to be able to plot both lines in one graph and take the average of the two, you need to some reshaping.

```
df_ag <- melt(df, id.vars=c("Type"))
df_ag_sb <- df_ag %>% group_by(Type, variable) %>% summarise(meanx = mean(as.numeric(value), na.rm=TRUE))

ggplot(df_ag_sb, aes(x=Type, y=as.numeric(meanx), color=variable, group=variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, Unfortunately, I made a mistake in the data set. I will modify the question now.